# NVL2 function does not exist? mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do some queries but I keep getting errors, now I'm thinking that there is something wrong with the mysql installation. Can anybody tell me if there is an error in this query?

```
         SELECT settings.ID, 
                settings.name, 
                settings.description, 
                NVL2(userSettings.value, userSettings.value, settings.default) 
           FROM settings 
LEFT OUTER JOIN userSettings ON (settings.ID = userSettings.settingID)
```

The error I get says the function databaseX.NVL2 does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because NVL2 is an Oracle function, not a MySQL function.  I believe the function you are looking for in MySQL would be [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: nvl2 is something different than NVL or COALESCE. You'll need CASE to replace this function.

Comment: IMHO, I recommend using a `CASE` statement.  It works with both Oracle and MySQL, so it's one less thing to change when translating SQL statements between the two DBs.  In this case:

Original Oracle SQL with `NVL2` function:
`NVL2(userSettings.value, userSettings.value, settings.default)`

Portable `CASE` statement:
`CASE WHEN userSettings.value is null THEN settings.default ELSE userSettings.value`

Answer (score 3):

I recommend staying away from vendor specific functions when a ANSI standard equivalent alternative is available. NVL and IFNULL for example can (often) be replaced with COALESCE.

You can also use `CASE WHEN`, which means a lot more typing on the downside, but the upside is that people with background in SQL Server for example won't have to deal with Oracles DECODE() or NVL or NVL2, because the logic is right there in the code.

Comment: +1 for case. nvl/ifnull/coalesce are no replacement for nvl2.

Comment: `CASE` is the best in this instance.  See [MySQL CASE documentation](http://goo.gl/pYCEY) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As @Eric Petroelje mentioned `NVL2()` is Oracle function, not MySQL. However MySQL has its own equivalent that can be used in this case: [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SELECT ... IFNULL(userSettings.value, settings.default) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

After several try&error probes, I found this method to emulate Oracle's NVL2 function. It's not very elegant, but  it works

```
SELECT IF(LENGTH(ISNULL(FieldName, '')) > 0, 'Not NULL Value', 'Null Value') FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you

[**IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns expr2; otherwise it returns expr3. IF() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can substitute NVL2 to:

```
IF (userSettings.value IS NULL, userSettings.value, settings.default)
```